# Avoid multiple ajax requests angularJS

Tags: angularjs, promise, q

I am trying to avoid multiple ajax requests to the server in a factory. I already added a small caching service, but it is not enough for what I aim: this factory can be called several times before the server responds, causing the generation of multiple requests to the server.

To avoid this I added a second promise object, which if the AJAX request have been performed and the object is not yet in cache, than it should wait for a second promise to be resolved, but looks like I am missing something.

This is my code:

```
myApp.factory('User', ['Restangular', '$q',
  function (Restangular, $q) {
    var userCache, alreadyRun = false;
    return {
      getUser: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer(), firstRun= $q.defer();

        if (!userCache && !alreadyRun) {
          alreadyRun = true;

          Restangular.all('user').getList().then(function (user) {
            console.log('getting user live ');
            userCache = user[0].email;
            firstRun.resolve(user[0].email);
          });
        } else if (!userCache && alreadyRun) {
          console.log('waiting for the first promise to be resolved ');
          firstRun.then(function(user) {
            console.log('resolving the promise');
            deferred.resolve(userCache);
          });

        } else {
          console.log('resolving the promise from the cache');
          deferred.resolve(userCache)
        }
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: I added my final implementation in the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just return the original promise if the request has already been made. Something like this should work;

```
myApp.factory('User', ['Restangular', '$q',
  function (Restangular, $q) {
    var deferred = false;

    return {
      getUser: function () {

        if(deferred) {
          return deferred.promise;
        }

        deferred = $q.defer();

        Restangular.all('user').getList().then(function (user) {
          deferred.resolve(user[0].email);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Also have a look at the [Restangular documentation for caching requests](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#can-i-cache-requests)

Comment: Thanks for sharing @smilledge . In the meanwhile from when I asked the question I implemented something by myself. However your solution looks really clean and compact so I accepted your answer. Have a look at mine and let me know what you think of it :)

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you run getUser, a new defer is created for firstRun. If it's already ran, you call firstRun.then, but that promise is never resolved.

Comment: But there is any way to achieve what am I trying to do?

Comment: Can't tell you without more context. GetUser is being called from a bunch of places at once? You can use Resolve on a route to make sure it's loaded before you start doing things.

Comment: Hi @JonathanRowny I added an answer with my own implementation, have a look and let me know what you think. I accepted as answer the one by smilledge because it looks really clean.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the answers, in the meanwhile I found a way to cache that particular factory:

```
.factory('User', ['Restangular', '$q',
  function (Restangular, $q) {
    var userCache, promises = [];
    return {

      getUser: function () {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        if (promises.length > 0) {

          promises.push(deferred);

        } else if (!userCache) {

          promises.push(deferred);

          Restangular.all('user').getList().then(function (user) {
            var i;
            userCache = user[0];
            for (i = promises.length; i--;) {
              promises.shift().resolve(userCache);
            }
          });

        } else {

          deferred.resolve(userCache);

        }

        return deferred.promise;

      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Basically the idea is to create an array of promises while `userCache` is not ready, then resolve the whole queue once the request is ready and finally directly resolve the promise with the cached value for each future request.

I described the implementation of this [promise caching here](http://maurizionapoleoni.de/blog/using-effective-promise-caching-in-factories-with-AngularJS.html).