# Lock in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, caching, cachefactory

I have a service that gets data related to the current logged in user from the server, which internally caches the returned user object. The user service:

```
    var appCache = $cacheFactory.get('appCache');
    var userInfoFromCache = appCache.get('userInfo');

    if (userInfoFromCache) {
        $log.debug("User info cache hit");            
        deferred.resolve(userInfoFromCache);
    } else{
        $log.debug("User info cache miss");
        //do work and get data from server
        appCache.put('userInfo', userInfo);
    }
```

The service works great. I am calling the user service from multiple places on load such as top navigation and inside the home view. I also call the service in run section of app.js:

```
.run(function(userService) {
    userService.getUser();
})
```

Since I am calling the service from multiple places at once, i am ending up with multiple server calls. Is there a way I can setup a lock on the code so that subsequent calls to the userService is served by cache?

Comment: You don't need to (and shouldn't) lock, just return the original promise if a call is already in progress. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125837/avoid-multiple-ajax-requests-angularjs

Comment: Awesome this helped! I was missing the check for deferred == true.

Comment: Do you mind posting as answer? I will mark yours as "the" answer. Thanks!

Comment: Tempting to collect my nerd points, but it'd basically be a duplicate answer so doesn't really seem worth preserving.  Glad I could help anyway!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid multiple ajax requests angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125837/avoid-multiple-ajax-requests-angularjs)